Enable POST body logging using modsecurity
I have been working on trying to get POST request BODY logging using modsecurity.
In the modecurity.conf file, I have enabled
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so
this is my entire modsecurity.conf file:
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "^(?:application(?:/soap\+|/)|text/)xml" \
     "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"

SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "^application/json" \
     "id:'200001',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=JSON"

SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject
SecRequestBodyJsonDepthLimit 512
SecArgumentsLimit 1000
SecRule &ARGS "@ge 1000" \
"id:'200007', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to fully parse request body due to large argument count',severity:2"

SecRule REQBODY_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200002', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2"

SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"id:'200003',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400, \
msg:'Multipart request body failed strict validation: \
PE %{REQBODY_PROCESSOR_ERROR}, \
BQ %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED}, \
BW %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_WHITESPACE}, \
DB %{MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE}, \
DA %{MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER}, \
HF %{MULTIPART_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
LF %{MULTIPART_LF_LINE}, \
SM %{MULTIPART_MISSING_SEMICOLON}, \
IQ %{MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING}, \
IP %{MULTIPART_INVALID_PART}, \
IH %{MULTIPART_INVALID_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
FL %{MULTIPART_FILE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED}'"

SecStreamInBodyInspection On
SecRule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY "@eq 1" \
    "id:'200004',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,msg:'Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary.'"

SecPcreMatchLimit 1000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 1000

SecRule TX:/^MSC_/ "!@streq 0" \
    "id:'200005',phase:2,t:none,log,deny,msg:'ModSecurity internal error flagged: %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}'"

SecResponseBodyAccess Off
SecResponseBodyMimeType text/plain text/html text/xml
SecResponseBodyLimit 524288
SecResponseBodyLimitAction ProcessPartial
SecTmpDir /tmp/
SecDataDir /tmp/
SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4(?!04))"
SecAuditLogParts ABCH
SecAuditLogType Serial
SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log
SecArgumentSeparator &
SecCookieFormat 0
SecUnicodeMapFile unicode.mapping 20127
SecStatusEngine Off

Now, the logs actually only output section A,B,H like below:
--7dd1fc75-A--
[12/Dec/2024:17:57:15.512829 +0000] Z1sj-0SllWNcXRhkj1sZUAAAAEo 

--7dd1fc75-B--
POST /logs HTTP/1.1

-7dd1fc75-E--

--7dd1fc75-H--
Apache-Error: [file "mod_authz_core.c"] [line 879] [level 3] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/logs

The request for which I want to examine this body actually gets a 403 as you can see above. But I still want to see the POST Request Body.
There are some questions related to this here, but I have tried everything. Can someone help me logs the POST body.
